# how to stop movement of force directed graph on force.start

Tags: d3.js, force-layout

I am using force directed graph to show topology data on graphical view. I have written below code:

```
var force = d3.layout.force()
        .charge(-120)
        .alpha(0)
        .linkDistance(65)
        .gravity(0.03)
        .size([width, height]);

force
      .nodes(data.nodes)
      .links(data.links)
      .start();
```

When i execute the code graph initialize with some movement which i need to stop. I want a graph display on static position without any movement and all links size should be same on graph initialization. if i will drag then it suppose to move. 
Any help would be much appreciated....!

Comment: It sounds like the force layout is not what you're looking for for this application. Have you considered any of the other layouts?

Comment: Actually we are developing network application so force directed graph is more suitable than others. Still you suggestion are most welcome. I looking for behavior like this http://jsfiddle.net/bTyh5/2  and my Jsfiddle is this : http://jsfiddle.net/mayurchavda87/5crQv/3/

Comment: If you don't want any movement, you could set the `.fixed` property on all nodes.

Comment: If the nodes are set to .fixed, the node will have to be positioned manually instead of running the force layout. I suppose the question is about positioning with the force layout but without the animation.

Comment: The way force layout works is that it will compute node position dynamically. If you really want fixed position, you'll have to set fixed property on all nodes (like Lars suggestion). You can run the layout (without display) first to compute all node positions and store them. Then during your animation, add the nodes to their respective positions.

Comment: I built this example with node 4 in fixed position and static layout. Check it out: https://vida.io/documents/fGzpzjP98Bs2ShMHW.

Answer (score 10):

Here is an example of [static force-directed layout](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1667139) initialization.

> "Rather than updating the graph with each tick, we run the graph a fixed number of times, and then display it once."

```
force.start();
for (var i = n * n; i > 0; --i) force.tick();
force.stop();
```

This doesn't prevent you from setting draggable nodes the usual way:

```
.call(force.drag);
```

You can help the links get the settle down to the size you want by controlling the [linkStrength](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Force-Layout#wiki-linkStrength)

Comment: what is "n"? my JSFIDDLE link: http://jsfiddle.net/mayurchavda87/5crQv/3/ Actually I am looking for this( http://jsfiddle.net/bTyh5/2/ ) type of behavior in my graph using setInterval function. when each time new ajax request made for update data graph is moving which i need to stop.

Comment: If you look at the example I link to, you can see that n is an arbitrary number of iterations of the force layout big enough to give a chance for the layout to converge. So every time you add a new node dynamically, you could run the layout in this kind of loop, bypassing the layout animation.

Comment: "n" is the number of nodes, check a complete code here. http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1667139